# gRPC streaming observer pattern under the hood

Tags: streaming, grpc, observers, grpc-java

Taking the server streaming gRPC API as an example. I’d like to understand if the StreamObserver that the client generates and sends as part of the initial request to the server actually gets sent over the wire for the server to then invoke directly. Or if what is actually happening is the client registers the observer and then gets notified to call onNext (or other) itself. Looking to understand this process a bit deeper than docs explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StreamObserver` is not sent over-the-wire; it is just used locally. The gRPC wire protocol sends metadata and messages between the client and server and the StreamObserver API locally converts events into callbacks.

You may also be interested in the [gRPC wire protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md).

Comment: that makes sense. So does the gRPC server send a message with some specific “ID” and indicate an action like “onNext” (with any respective value). Then client receives message with ID/action/value so it can use proper registered observer for that “ID” and call proper action (onNext/onCompleted) with value?

Comment: The entire RPC exists over a single "HTTP exchange" (request+response). Metadata is encoded as HTTP headers+trailers and messages are encoded as request/response content with message lengths prefixed. Not all that special. The StreamObserver is thus tied to the exchange. HTTP/2 itself can multiplex multiple HTTP exchanges ("streams" in HTTP/2) onto a single connection. And yes, HTTP/2 uses a stream id to separate the content for the different exchanges.

Comment: Does the message content (vs metadata) have the data indicating which observer a client should use (assuming another ID or maybe even the stream ID itself is specific enough) to handle a received server message? I assume the client side gRPC code stores these observers in a map with this ID. Also, does this data explicitly have which particular method to call (onNext vs onComplete)? Perhaps that’s unnecessary and onNext is implicitly the default observer method called whereas onComplete will be called on messages after a certain header or status (and same for onError)?

Comment: It is all just scoped to a stream/HTTP exchange. Each frame in HTTP/2 has a "stream id" which is used to look up state for that stream. OnNext() is for data and OnComplete() is for end-stream (client→server)/end-stream-and-OK-status (server→client). In HTTP/2 in particular, see https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9113.html#FrameHeader which has "Stream Identifier" and "flag" END_STREAM. Server→client uses HEADERS at the end of the exchange to communicate status code. See https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9113.html#rfc.section.8.1 for how HTTP concepts are mapped to HTTP/2.